# App built with xCode 7.3 won't install on iPhone 4/iOS 7.3.1

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have an app that is built and deployed to the app store with xCode 7.3, but does not install on iPhone 4 with iOS 7.1.   The supported architectures are arm64, armv7, armv7s and the iOS Deployment Target is set to iOS 5.1.1.

Any ideas as to what other settings could affect the ability of an app to be installed on iPhone 4/iOS 7.1 when built with xCode 7.3.  Previous versions built with xCode 6 worked ok.

Comment: What is the error you got when you want to install on iPhone4??

Answer (score 0):

Ok it turns out the app was actually installing but was crashing immediately on startup due to *use of an api not supported in the older iOS 7.1* which is the maximum iOS version that can be upgraded to on an iPhone 4. The invalid method being used was NSString *contains:*

One challenge for testing on iPhone 4 devices is that TestFlight doesn't install on those devices (TestFlight needs iOS 8.0+) and xCode 7.3 also doesn't support download of an iOS 7.1 Simulator build. So manual install onto physical device was required to reproduce.